# Access to the port 'COM1' is denied from time controller

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, serial-port, modbus

This is my code. In this code I am calling from time in every second bit I am getting

> error comp port access denied

I am getting this after 5 calls.

```
using (SerialPort port = new SerialPort(serialPortName))
    {
        if (port.IsOpen)
        {
            port.Close();
            port.Dispose();
        }

        port.BaudRate = 19200;
        port.DataBits = 8;
        port.Parity = Parity.None;
        port.StopBits = StopBits.Two;

        port.Open();

        // create modbus master
        IModbusSerialMaster master = ModbusSerialMaster.CreateRtu(port);
        byte slaveId = Convert.ToByte(txtSlaveId.Text.Trim());
        ushort startAddress = Convert.ToUInt16(StartAddress);
        ushort numRegisters = Convert.ToUInt16(NumberofRegisters);

        SystemLog systemLog = new SystemLog();
        systemLog.SlaveId = txtSlaveId.Text.Trim();
        systemLog.VariableName = VariableName;
        systemLog.ReadStartTime = DateTime.Now;

        switch (Type)
        {
            case "CO":
                bool[] status = master.ReadCoils(slaveId, startAddress, numRegisters);
                for (int j = 0; j < numRegisters; j++)
                {
                    systemLog.ReadEndTime = DateTime.Now;
                    systemLog.ReadAddress = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(StartAddress) + j);
                    systemLog.ReadType = (int)PLCReadType.COIL;
                    systemLog.ReadValue = Convert.ToString(status[j]);

                }
                break;
            case "IR":
                ushort[] inputRegister = master.ReadInputRegisters(slaveId, startAddress, numRegisters);
                for (int j = 0; j < numRegisters; j++)
                {
                    systemLog.ReadEndTime = DateTime.Now;
                    systemLog.ReadAddress = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(StartAddress) + j);
                    systemLog.ReadType = (int)PLCReadType.COIL;
                    systemLog.ReadValue = Convert.ToString(inputRegister[j]);

                }
                break;
            case "HR":
                ushort[] holdingRegister = master.ReadHoldingRegisters(slaveId, startAddress, numRegisters);
                for (int j = 0; j < numRegisters; j++)
                {
                    systemLog.ReadEndTime = DateTime.Now;
                    systemLog.ReadAddress = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(StartAddress) + j);
                    systemLog.ReadType = (int)PLCReadType.COIL;
                    systemLog.ReadValue = Convert.ToString(holdingRegister[j]);
                }
                break;
        }
        systemLogArray[i] = systemLog;
        port.Close();
        port.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Programmers are too over-eager to Close() a serial port.  This is not compatible with the way the SerialPort class was designed.  Nor is it *ever* beneficial to allow another program to steal the port away from you and get your program to randomly crash.  The MSDN docs for SerialPort.Close warn about this, there is a worker thread that needs to exit before the port is usable again, the one that generates the events.  Exactly how long that takes is unpredictable.  The only sane way to do this is to open the port when you start your program and not close it until it ends.

Comment: @HansPassant You should post this as an Answer I think? It sounds good enough to be upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Hans Passant pointed out a very crucial issue. You should consider this.

Your problem sounds like a timing issue. It seems that your last instance is not disposed and the port is released yet to be used again.

I would advise to open the port before the loop. Do all your necessary reading every second, and when you are finished close it again.
Please remove the using block. The port does not need to be feeded nor will it give you performance advantages by getting rid of it 60 times in a minute.

if you look on this piece of code:

```
using (SerialPort port = new SerialPort(serialPortName))
    {
        if (port.IsOpen)
        {
            port.Close();
            port.Dispose();
        }
```

If you create a new `SerialPort` it is by default closed. The If-clause becomes obsolete, and instead of using a `using` block a `try/catch` would be more appropriate.

this line: `port.Dispose();` at the end of your code is also superfluous (or it makes the using block superfluous), because the `using` block will do exactly this at the end.

Comment: i put the 
using (SerialPort port = new SerialPort(serialPortName))
    {
        if (port.IsOpen)
        {
            port.Close();
            port.Dispose();
        } this block above the for loop now same thing is happening after 5 call its giving me access denied after 5 call

Comment: @PallavJha could you please post the code with the loop. I think it is decisive to understand your problem

Comment: @PallavJha which for-loop are you talking about? this: `for (int j = 0; j < numRegisters; j++)` ? What exactly do you mean with "I am calling from time in every second " you call this code with the using-block every second?